# How to use the whole space when placing ConstraintLayout inside a NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

I'm trying to put a `ConstraintLayout` inside a `NestedScrollView`, but there is a line that separates the `ConstraintLayout`. I can't place anything underneath that invisible line. I have been trying for hours and can't find the issue.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/premium_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#BFFFFFFF"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:tag="layout/fragment_premium"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".PremiumFragment">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/launcher_id"
                android:layout_width="185dp"
                android:layout_height="185dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/premium_text_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/launch_premium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/premium_text_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
                android:text="@string/launch_to_premium"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
                android:layout_width="383dp"
                android:layout_height="196dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/premium_text_id" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of messing around I was able to get what you are looking for. The key is to use `android:fillViewport="true"` in the NestedScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/premium_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#BFFFFFFF"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:tag="layout/fragment_premium">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/launcher_id"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/launch_premium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/premium_text_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/launch_to_premium"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/launcher_id" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
                android:layout_width="383dp"
                android:layout_height="196dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/premium_text_id" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a attribute `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `NestedScrollView`

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/premium_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#BFFFFFFF"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:fillViewport="true" <-- add this
        android:tag="layout/fragment_premium">
```

why?
`fillViewport` allows NestedScrollView to extend its height equals to the full height of the device screen height in the cases when the child of scroll view has less height.
[this](https://demonuts.com/android-fillviewport/) blog Will explain more about it.